# Convert PHP String to 1 UTF-8 character

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding

```
$caption = "Hello World \xF0"; // \xF0 is evaluated as one character
$input = $_POST["mes"]; // \xF0 is stored as four characters
// equivalent to:
$input = 'Hello World \xF0'; // \xF0 also stored as four characters
```

How can I encode my $input string to get \xF0 also as one character ? 
Thank you very much !

Comment: "What" is sending the POST parameter `mes`? I'm asking because \x can transport one byte as `\xnn` but there are also other interpretations (which mostly should be `\unnnn`). Is \x in your case always a hexadecimal literal notation of exactly one byte (`\xnn`) ? How is the character `Ü` transfered? As `\xC3\x9C` or `\x00DC` or `\u00DC` or ... ?

Comment: @VolkerK This is one example for my ` $_POST["mes"]  -> \xF0\x9F\x98\x9A ` . It comes via Ajax from a HTML Form. But if I do strlen I get 16 Chars if I type directly into PHP I get 1 Char as result of strlen.

Comment: And that would be `KISSING FACE WITH CLOSED EYES` smiley?

Comment: @Johnny2312 the problem is on the other end (the sender) that encodes data incorrectly. So I would suggest to fix it since that's what originates the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$data = '\xF0\x9F\x98\x9A';

$pattern = '!
    \\\                     # a literal backslash
    x                       # followed by a literal x
    (                       # capture the following {
        [0-9a-fA-F]         #   any hexadecimal digit
        {2}                 #   actually two of them
    )                       # }
!x';

// replace all \xnn by "the byte nn"
$data = preg_replace_callback(
    $pattern,
    function($captures) {
        return chr( hexdec($captures[1]) );
    },
    $data
);

// $data contains now the byte sequence given by the hexadecimal notation
// but keep in mind that php3,4,5's core has no notion of character encoding
// a string is just a sequence of single bytes...

// I'm using a browser to display the result
// it must know that the output stream is utf-8 encoded
// default_charset will send the appropriate http response header for that
ini_set('default_charset', 'utf-8');

echo $data;
```

prints a  in my firefox

Comment: That's a bit harmful to suggest newbies to fix the consequences instead of the root of the problem

Comment: Yes, but I'm not sure whether there is a `root of the problem` that is fixable. That depends on the other side of the AJAX-thingy....

Comment: Sure, that's why I personally would continue that chat in the question comments to see what exactly breaks it. +1 for solving "the problem" though :-)